# What's the difference between `curl | sh` and `sh -c "$(curl)"`?

Tags: shell, pipe, curl, docker, command-substitution

One easy install method for Docker (for example) is this:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

However, I have also seen some that look like this (using the Docker example):

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/)"
```

They appear to be functionally the same, but is there a reason to use one over the other?  Or is it just a preference/aesthetic thing?

(Of note, be very careful when running script from unknown origins.)

Comment: Is it weird that I trust docker to install an entire software execution platform on my computer, but I don't trust the website not to put junk into my `| sh` command?  This makes me uneasy.  Like maybe I need to spend some time considering what would happen if I entered `<html>internal server error</html>` into sh.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a practical difference.

`curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` starts `curl` and `sh` at the same time, connecting the output of `curl` with the input of `sh`. `curl` will carry out with the download (roughly) as fast as `sh` can run the script. The server can [detect the irregularities in the timing](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2016/04/detecting-curl-pipe-bash-server-side/) and inject malicious code not visible when simply downloading the resource into a file or buffer or when viewing it in a browser.

In `sh -c "$(curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/)"`, `curl` is run strictly before the `sh` is run. The whole contents of the resource are downloaded and passed to your shell before the `sh` is started. Your shell only starts `sh` when `curl` has exited, and passes the text of the resource to it. The server cannot detect the `sh` call; it is only started after the connection ends. It is similar to downloading the script into a file first.

(This may not relevant in the docker case, but it may be a problem in general and highlights a practical difference between the two commands.)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the most important difference between the two.

Comment: Could you cite a resource backing up this claim please? I'd be very interested in knowing how the server can detect the 'sh' call.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Uhm, I put a link on the ``vulnerable to server-side detection`` phrase. It leads to a blog post which explains in great detail how they achieve it. TL;DR: put a sleep in your script and observe the delay in reception on the server.

Comment: @JonasWielicki thanks - the link wasn't very clear - not your fault, down to SE's CSS I think. People are brilliantly sneaky, aren't they? :)

Comment: This is actually rather interesting. It might be worth noting here that to detect the pipe, the server must output a rather large amount of data (just the pipe buffer is something like 64 kB on Linux). That should be rather obvious if one saves the script to a file, or looks at it with something like `less` (which shows control characters and NUL bytes). Plus, if the server outputs a script of more than 128 kB, then `bash -c "$(curl ...)"` won't work since the kernel limits the size of a single command line argument.

Comment: All of which leads me to wonder if anyone has ever tried to do that trick in reality without getting immediately caught. Not that it probably matters much since you could probably just have the script do something malicious even without such tricks, and anyone who doesn't read it in full would be vulnerable.

Answer (score 14):

I believe that they are practically identical. However, there are rare cases where they are different.

`$(cmd)` gets substituted with the results of `cmd`.  Should the length of that result command exceeds the maximum argument length value returned by `getconf ARG_MAX`, it will truncate the result, which may result in unpredictable results.

The pipe option does not have this limitation.  Each line of output from the `curl` command will be executed by `bash` as it arrives from the pipe.

But ARG_MAX is usually in the 256,000 character range. For a docker install, I'd be confident using either method.  :-)

Comment: Interesting, so there is a difference. Thanks

Comment: When in doubt, use the pipe method.  I didn't specify a preference in my answer, but I would prefer the pipe method for this kind of use because you never know how much data is coming through the pipe.

Comment: "it will truncate the result" -- The shell should issue an error message for that, not silently truncate. When testing, I even get an error from the shell far below `ARG_MAX`, bash limits an individual argument to 131072 bytes on my system, when `getconf ARG_MAX` prints `2097152`. But either way, error or truncation, it wouldn't work.

Comment: But [old implementations](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) of Bourne shell had much lower limits. In 4.2BSD the limit was 10240 characters, and on earlier systems it was even lower.. Of course that was 30 years ago, so you're unlikely to encounter such low limits today.

If I recall correctly, some of these early shells did just silently truncate.

Comment: The 128 kB limit for a single argument is a Linux thing, it's not about Bash.

Answer (score 11):

In `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`:

- Both commands, `curl` and `sh`, will start at the same time, in respective subshells
- The STDOUT from `curl` will be passed as the STDIN to `sh` (this is what pipe, `|`, does)

Whereas in `sh -c "$(curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/)"`:

- The command substitution, `$()`, will be executed first i.e. `curl` will be run first in a subshell
- The command substitution, `$()`, will be replaced by the STDOUT from `curl`
- `sh -c` (non-interactive, non-login shell) will execute the STDOUT from `curl`

Comment: So, is there any real difference?

Comment: @Sarke Yes, theoretically like i mentioned, but practically hardly noticeable. (There would be visible effect if you leave the command substitution unquoted.)

Comment: @Sarke, if the scripts is not downloaded completely, you wouldn't necessarily notice it with piping. The process getting piped to can ignore that signal.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen what do you mean with not downloaded completely? Why would that happen except for a server error in which case there won't be anything piped to sh.

Comment: Or connection interruption... there are so many ways a transfer can fail

Answer (score 4):

With pipe version you loose script interactivity, as you pipe curl stdout to sh stdin. So no keyboard input and possible script crash when awaiting input.

Other answers here are also important.

Answer (score 2):

One difference between the two (taken from other answers across the web) is that if you don't download the entire script at once, it could cut off half way through the script at an unknown point and change the meaning of the command to be executed. So it seems first downloading the whole file and then evaluating it would be better.